# Porting 32-bit to 64-bit MFC application in window 7

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, 32bit-64bit

I am porting 32-bit application to **64-bit** which is built in **VC++.net 2003**. I have built this application in **VS2010 sp1** successfully in **32-bit** and **64-bit** platform. But I am facing application crash issues in **64-bit platform(x64)** application but not in **32-bit platform(win32)**. Crashing is happening at belowcode line

```
char *pSls = (char*)SendMessage( ::GetParent( ::GetParent( GetParen() ) ),
                                              m_uMessageID,
                                              L_SOM_CHANNEL, nChannel );
```

In **win32 *pSls** get data in it but in **64-bit**, Expression doesn't evaluate.
I have observed return type of SendMessage is LRESULT which is a LONG_PTR and LONG_PTR is long in **Win32 and _int64 in 64-bit** platform. 
Could anyone please help to resolve issue?

Actual error which is displaiying: 
Expression: !IsBadReadPtr((const void *)(pszString), sizeof(*(pszString)))

Please find more code:

```
int CMNEditInputTab::GetChanIndx( const int nChannel )
{
   MEMBERASSERT();
   char *pSls = (char *)SendMessage( ::GetParent( ::GetParent( GetParent() ) ),
                                              m_uMessageID,
                                              L_SOM_CHANNEL, nChannel );

   if ( *pSls == NULL )
      return 0;

   int nIndex = GetSignalList().FindString( -1, pSls );

   if ( nIndex != LB_ERR )
      return nIndex;

   return 0;
}
int SN_ListBox::FindString( int nStartIndex, LPCTSTR pszString )
{
   MEMBERASSERT();
   RPTRASSERT(pszString);

   SN_REQUIRES_HWND( SN_ListBox::FindString );

   if ( m_hWnd )
      return ListBox_FindString(m_hWnd, nStartIndex, pszString);
   else
      return 0;
}
void MDCDBG_assert(char *pszExp, char *pszFile, int nLine)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
   MDCDBG_Initialize();
#ifndef _WIN32_WCE
   int nResponse = _CrtDbgReport(_CRT_ASSERT, pszFile, nLine, NULL, "%s", pszExp);
   if (nResponse == 1)
      _CrtDbgBreak();
#endif

#endif
}
```

In dbgrpt.c file:

```
_CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportT(
        int nRptType,
        const TCHAR * szFile,
        int nLine,
        const TCHAR * szModule,
        const TCHAR * szFormat,
        ...
        )
{
    int retval;
    va_list arglist;

    va_start(arglist,szFormat);

    retval = _CrtDbgReportTV(nRptType, szFile, nLine, szModule, szFormat, arglist);//Fails here

    va_end(arglist);

    return retval;
}
```

Observation:
*pSls is not getting data in x64 mode but this variable gets data in win32 mode

Comment: there is a star after char.

Comment: Are you getting the crash in the SendMessage or in one of the GetParents?  Try assigning them separately and see if it actually gets to the SendMessage

Comment: Application is crashing because of *pSls is not getting any data/string, that string I am passing in one of the function but as expression has not evaluated, it is acting as a bad pointer and hence crashing.

Comment: If I save return value in some variable abc then I could see 10 numeric value in it but in Win32, 8 numeric value for abc. LRESULT abc = SendMessage( ::GetParent( ::GetParent( GetParent() ) ),
                                              m_uMessageID,
                                              L_SOM_CHANNEL, nChannel );

Comment: You can step into the SendMessage to find out where it goes to and what it is trying to return.  It is not like a PostMessage which goes on a queue.

Comment: This line of code cannot possibly fail with an access violation (presumably). Unless `m_uMessageID`, `L_SOM_CHANNEL`, or `nChannel` are custom data types with conversion operators to the respective argument types, that can fail. Either way, it is way too little code to allow us to help you. Start by describing the **specific** error you are getting, the expected result and the observed behavior.

Comment: It is you handler that takes and handles the L_SOM_CHANNEL message. Check it. Check the code and the return value. Probably you use a wrong cast.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to determine the cause.  If I'm allowed to speculate, I have seen issues like this before.  It looks like the return of your SendMessage() returns a LPCTSTR?

My hunch... You have some string...

```
LPCTSTR lpszRet  = "abcdef"; // ignore error that this string might be on the stack
return (DWORD) lpszRet; // DWORD, or LONG, etc..., but error is here with pointer truncation
```

instead use,

```
return (DWORD_PTR) lpszRet; // or LONG_PTR, etc  ... pointer not truncated
```